# Approach to consume stream, transform, then hand to other consumers (without state)

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

New to Rx; trying to figure it out.

I am taking data from an accelerometer via events, adapting the data to my own format, then providing a data stream to other consumers via Reactive Extensions.

My approach is partially working in that an important constructor is being called.  Can someone look at this and help me understand what I should do differently?

Hopefully, this snippet is sufficient:

```
public class accel_raw_producer : IObservable<AccelerometerFrame_raw>
{
   private static Spatial spatial = null;
   private IObservable<EventPattern<SpatialDataEventArgs>> spatialEvents;

   public accel_raw_producer ()
   {
      spatial = new Spatial();
      spatial.close();
      spatialEvents = System.Reactive.Linq.Observable.FromEventPattern
         <SpatialDataEventHandler, SpatialDataEventArgs>(
         handler => handler.Invoke,
         h => spatial.SpatialData += h,
         h => spatial.SpatialData -= h);
      subscription = spatialEvents.Subscribe();
      spatial.open(-1);
   }


   public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<AccelerometerFrame_raw> observer)
   {
      return
         (from evt in spatialEvents
         let e = evt.EventArgs
         select new AccelerometerFrame_raw
         (
            e.spatialData[0].Acceleration[0],
            e.spatialData[0].Acceleration[1],
            e.spatialData[0].Acceleration[2],
            e.spatialData[0].AngularRate[0],
            e.spatialData[0].AngularRate[1],
            e.spatialData[0].AngularRate[2]
         )).Subscribe();
   }
}

public consumerClass :IObserver<AccelerometerFrame_raw>
{
   accel_raw_producer accelStream;
   IDisposable Unsubscriber;

   public consumerClass()
   {
      accelStream = new accel_raw_producer();
      Unsubscriber = accelStream.Subscribe(this);
   }

   public void OnCompleted()
   {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
   }

   public void OnError(Exception error)
   {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
   }

   public void OnNext(AccelerometerFrame_raw accelFrame)
   {
      if (null == accelFrame) return;
      AccelX = accelFrame.Acceleration.X;
      AccelY = accelFrame.Acceleration.Y;
      AccelZ = accelFrame.Acceleration.Z;
      GyroX = accelFrame.Rotation.X;
      GyroY = accelFrame.Rotation.Y;
      GyroZ = accelFrame.Rotation.Z;
   }    
}
```

When I set a breakpoint in AccelerometerFrame_raw, it gets triggered, but the values are not propagating up to the consumer.  So something in this method needs to be different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm missing some details here, but you don't appear to be using the observer input parameter and the subscribe doesn't really do anything with the onNext value. Personally, I would consider swinging this around and just passing out the IObservable and let the caller subscribe to it themselves:

```
public IObservable<AccelerometerFrame_raw> AccelerometerFrames()
{
     return
        from evt in spatialEvents
        let e = evt.EventArgs
        select new AccelerometerFrame_raw
        (
           e.spatialData[0].Acceleration[0],
           e.spatialData[0].Acceleration[1],
           e.spatialData[0].Acceleration[2],
           e.spatialData[0].AngularRate[0],
           e.spatialData[0].AngularRate[1],
           e.spatialData[0].AngularRate[2]
        );
}
```

Comment: When I try that, I get a compiler error:   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.IObservable<RxSpatial.AccelerometerFrame_raw>' to 'System.IDisposable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a a cast?)    That is what made me try out a few things like .AsObservable() and .Subscribe() to see if they worked.  Also note I added more code to the Original Post so you could see the relationship between the producer class and the consumer class.  The OnNext is there in the consumer class.

Comment: Okay, something is wrong with my last comment. I did not realize you had changed the return type on the method.  Now that I see that, it makes me wonder, if I do that, then what do I put in my Subscribe method?

Comment: Nothing - you don't call it yourself. You return the observable so that the caller can call `Subscribe(onNext)` itself.

Comment: In other words, you don't call `Subscribe`, the caller calls `Subscribe` on the observable that you're returning.

Comment: Look carefully at the `Subscribe` extension method overloads. You'll notice that there are many different forms of "observer" that can be supplied.

Comment: Jim, your suggestion has worked and I am now progressing.  Thanks also to Dave Sexton.  Your comments helped me understand it better.